# Can Application Center send push notification to Windows devices when an update is availble?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

According to the below link, Application Center can send push notification when an update is available. It says that Application Center can send for iOS and Android mobile client,but not for blackberry. But it didn't mention about windows devices.

[Push notifications of application updates](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/c_ac_push_notif.html?lang=en)

Can Application Center  send push notification to windows devices(not windows phone) mobile client automatically?

Comment: who is "we" and why are you excluding everyone else?

Comment: I meant "we" as people who use application center. I edidted this question.

Comment: thats a .... extremely weird choice of words

Comment: if you are talking about windows desktop or laptop, I doubt. For mobile device,just test it in local. Push notification for android works same way in test and prod, so I think it will be same for windows as well.

Comment: Thanks specializt1,  I will be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Application Center does not support push notifications for Windows apps.